# Unit testing Angular filter which relies on service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm attempting to test a custom filter I've built. The issue I'm running into is that this filter relies on an asynchronous call through a service. Below is my relevant filter code first, then my current test:

```
.filter('formatValue', ['serverService', '_', function(serverService, _) {
  var available = null;
  var serviceInvoked = false;

  function formatValue(value, code) {
    var details = _.findWhere(available, {code: code});
    if (details) {
      return details.unitSymbol + parts.join('.');
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }

  getAvailable.$stateful = true;
  function getAvailable(value, code) {
    if (available === null) {
      if (!serviceInvoked) {
        serviceInvoked = true;
        serverService.getAvailable().$promise.then(function(data) {
          available = data;
        });
      }
    } else {
      return formatValue(value, code);
    }
  }
  return getAvailable;
}])
```

test:

```
describe('filters', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('underscore');
    module('gameApp.filters');
  });

  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('serverService', function() {
      var getAvailable = function() {
        return {
          // mock object here
        };
      };
      return {
        getAvailable: getAvailable
      };
    });
  }));

  describe('formatValue', function() {

    it('should format values', inject(function(formatValueFilter) {
      expect(formatValueFilter(1000, 'ABC')).toEqual('å1000');
    }));
  });
});
```

The error I'm encountering when running my tests is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'serverService.getAvailable().$promise.then')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mock service needs to return a resolved promise. You can do this by injecting $q and returning `$q.when(data)`

However, I would think about refactoring this filter first. Filters are intended to be fast computations and probably should not be dependent on an asynchronous call. I would suggest moving your http call to a controller, then pass in the data needed to the filter.